# Continuous capture causes the camera preview to freeze after 3 minutes

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera2

I am trying to capture the image every 1 second. I use a handler for the task. Here is the code for that part.

```
val handler = Handler()
 button.setOnClickListener {
            prepareUIForCapture()
            if(isRunning){
                handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)
                restartActivity()
            }else{
                button.text = "Stop"
                handler.postDelayed(object : Runnable {
                    override fun run(){
                        twoLens.reset()
                        twoLens.isTwoLensShot = true
                        MainActivity.cameraParams.get(dualCamLogicalId).let {
                            if (it?.isOpen == true) {
                                Logd("In onClick. Taking Dual Cam Photo on logical camera: " + dualCamLogicalId)
                                takePicture(this@MainActivity, it)                                
                                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Captured", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                            }
                        }

                        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000)
                    }
                }, 1000)
            }
            isRunning = !isRunning
        }
    }
```

This works as intended, however after around 3 minutes, the camera preview lags and the capture stops and eventually the application crashes.

Here is the code for `takePicture()`

```
fun takePicture(activity: MainActivity, params: CameraParams) {
    if (!params.isOpen) {
        return
    }

    try {
        Logd("In captureStillPicture.")
        val camera = params.captureSession?.getDevice()

        if (null != camera) {
            params.captureBuilder = camera.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE)
//            params.captureBuilder?.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE)
            params.captureBuilder?.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_AUTO)

            if (params.id.equals(dualCamLogicalId) && twoLens.isTwoLensShot) {

                val normalParams: CameraParams? = MainActivity.cameraParams.get(normalLensId)
                val wideParams: CameraParams? = MainActivity.cameraParams.get(wideAngleId)

                if (null == normalParams || null == wideParams)
                    return

                Logd("In captureStillPicture. This is a Dual Cam shot.")

                params.captureBuilder?.addTarget(normalParams.imageReader?.surface!!)
                params.captureBuilder?.addTarget(wideParams.imageReader?.surface!!)

            }
            params.captureBuilder?.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_QUALITY, 50)
            // Orientation
            val rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation()
            var capturedImageRotation = getOrientation(params, rotation)
            params.captureBuilder?.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, capturedImageRotation)

            try {
                params.captureSession?.stopRepeating()

            } catch (e: CameraAccessException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }            
            //Do the capture
            if (28 <= Build.VERSION.SDK_INT )
                params.captureSession?.captureSingleRequest(params.captureBuilder?.build(), params.backgroundExecutor, StillCaptureSessionCallback(activity, params))
            else
                params.captureSession?.capture(params.captureBuilder?.build(), StillCaptureSessionCallback(activity, params),
                    params.backgroundHandler)

        }
    } catch (e: CameraAccessException) {
        e.printStackTrace()

    } catch (e: IllegalStateException) {
        Logd("captureStillPicture IllegalStateException, aborting: " + e)
    }
}
```

Here is the part to create the preview.

```
fun createCameraPreviewSession(activity: MainActivity, camera: CameraDevice, params: CameraParams) {
    Logd("In createCameraPreviewSession.")
    if (!params.isOpen) {
        return
    }

    try {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 28 && params.id.equals(MainActivity.dualCamLogicalId)) {
            val normalParams: CameraParams? = MainActivity.cameraParams.get(normalLensId)
            val wideParams: CameraParams? = MainActivity.cameraParams.get(wideAngleId)

            Logd("In createCameraPreview. This is a Dual Cam stream. Starting up simultaneous streams.")

            if (null == normalParams || null == wideParams)
                return

//          val normalTexture = normalParams.previewTextureView?.surfaceTexture
            val wideTexture = wideParams.previewTextureView?.surfaceTexture

//          if (null == normalTexture || null == wideTexture)
//                return

//          normalTexture.setDefaultBufferSize(400,400)
            wideTexture!!.setDefaultBufferSize(400,400)

//          val normalSurface = Surface(normalTexture)
            val wideSurface = Surface(wideTexture)

            val wideOutputConfigPreview = OutputConfiguration(wideSurface)
            val wideOutputConfigImageReader = OutputConfiguration(wideParams.imageReader?.surface!!)
            wideOutputConfigPreview.setPhysicalCameraId(wideAngleId)
            wideOutputConfigImageReader.setPhysicalCameraId(wideAngleId)

//          val normalOutputConfigPreview = OutputConfiguration(normalSurface)
            val normalOutputConfigImageReader = OutputConfiguration(normalParams.imageReader?.surface!!)
            normalOutputConfigImageReader.setPhysicalCameraId(normalLensId)

            val sessionConfig = SessionConfiguration(SessionConfiguration.SESSION_REGULAR,
                Arrays.asList( normalOutputConfigImageReader, wideOutputConfigPreview, wideOutputConfigImageReader),
                params.backgroundExecutor, PreviewSessionStateCallback(activity, params))

            params.previewBuilder = camera.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW)
//          params.previewBuilder?.addTarget(normalSurface)
            params.previewBuilder?.addTarget(wideSurface)

            camera.createCaptureSession(sessionConfig)

        } else {
            val texture = params.previewTextureView?.surfaceTexture

            if (null == texture)
                return

            val surface = Surface(texture)

            if (null == surface)
                return

            params.previewBuilder = camera.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW)
            params.previewBuilder?.addTarget(surface)

            val imageSurface = params.imageReader?.surface
            if (null == imageSurface)
                return

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 28) {
                val sessionConfig = SessionConfiguration(SessionConfiguration.SESSION_REGULAR,
                    Arrays.asList(OutputConfiguration(surface), OutputConfiguration(imageSurface)),
                    params.backgroundExecutor, PreviewSessionStateCallback(activity, params))

                camera.createCaptureSession(sessionConfig)

            } else {
                camera.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface, imageSurface),
                    PreviewSessionStateCallback(activity, params), params.backgroundHandler)
            }

        }

    } catch (e: CameraAccessException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    } catch (e: IllegalStateException) {
        Logd("createCameraPreviewSession IllegalStateException, aborting: " + e)
    }
}
```

I tried clearing the buffers and bitmaps, but the issue persists. I am thinking I might not be using the correct approach towards continuous capture. Is this way correct? 
Any idea why the preview freezes?

Here is the original repo: https://github.com/google/basicbokeh
I did changes to suit my needs since it did not run on my device (HWMate20Pro) off the shelf and I needed continuous captures from both lenses.

Thanks.

Comment: Where is the code for the Preview? and for "takePicture()" method? How can we answer you without ANY useful code?

Comment: Sorry, added the missing methods.

Comment: *and eventually the application crashes* — what does logcat say about this?

Comment: No error or warning, but garbage collection starts.

Comment: Is it possible that you are not closing the image object in onImageAvailable listener when you take pictures. It might be one of the possible reasons for your issue.